# PHP - Sistema de Login

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estou criando um sistema de login e gostaria de saber o que está ocasionando os erros

Notice: Undefined variable: e in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 14

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getMessage() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\CLASSES\usuarios.php:14 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\login\index_vacc.php(57): Usuario->conectar('projeto_login', 'localhost', 'root', '') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\login\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 14

O index é:

```php
<?php
    require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
    $u = new Usuario();
?>

<html lang="pt-br">
<body>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="content first-content">

            <div class="first-column">
                <h2 class="title title-grey">Olá, bem vindo(a) à plataforma</h2>
                <h2 class="title title-grey">de prestação de contas.</h2>

            </div>

            <div class="second-column">
                <h2 class="title title-white">Entrar</h2>
                <p class="description">Faça o login para o acesso</p>
                <form method="POST">
                    <label class="label-input" for="">
                        <i class="far fa-envelope icon-modify"></i>

                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="   E-mail">
                    </label>
                    <label class="label-input" for="">
                        <i class="fas fa-lock icon-modify"></i>

                        <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="   Senha">
                    </label>
                    <button type ="submit" class="btn btn-grey">login</button>
                </form>

            </div>
            </div>
    </div>
            <?php  
                if(isset($_POST['email']))
                {
                    $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
                    $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);


                    if(!empty($email) && !empty($senha))
                    {
                        $u->conectar("projeto_login", "localhost", "root", "");
                    if($u->msgErro == "")
                        {
                        if($u->logar($email,$senha))
                        {
                            header("location: AreaPrivada.php");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Email e/ou senha estão incorretos!";
                        }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "Preencha todos os campos!";
                    }
                }
            ?>
</body>

</html>
```

E a parte de funções de conexão:

```php
<?php  

Class Usuario
{
    private $pdo;  
    public $msgErro = "";

    public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        global $msgErro;
        try {
            $pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host, $usuario, $senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            $msgErro = $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
        global $pdo;
        $sql = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s", md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $dado = $sql->fetch();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dado['id_usuario'];
             return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Já tentei declarar um public $e mas aparentemente não funcionou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro apresentado está informando que não é possível acessar o método `getMessage` de um objeto nulo, nesse caso da variável `$e` pois ocorreu algum erro que impediu a correta captura da exceção que ocorreu em `$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host, $usuario, $senha);`

Para corrigir:
Você precisa utilizar o `$this` que guarda a referência a própria classe, junto com `->` para conseguir acessar as variáveis/atributos da classe dentro dos métodos `conectar` e `logar`, como as variáveis: `$pdo` e `$msgErro` que foram declaradas no início da classe.

E NÃO vai precisar usar variáveis globais como havia aqui:

```
global $pdo;
global $msgErro;
```

Pois pode-se acessá-las como expliquei acima usando `$this->nomeDaVariavelDaClasse`.

O erro que estava ocorrendo com as variáveis globais tem ligação com a referência as variáveis globais, que podem assumir valores inesperados da forma com que estavam sendo utilizadas aqui. Para ver mais informações sobre as variáveis globais caso necessite usar futuramente (nesse caso não precisa):
[Escopo de variáveis](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.scope.php)

Possíveis modificações utilizando o `$this->nomeDaVariavelDaClasse` no Arquivo usuarios.php:

```
<?php  

Class Usuario
{
    private $pdo;  
    public $msgErro = "";

    public function conectar($nome, $host, $usuario, $senha)
    {
        try {
//aqui use $this->
            $this->pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$nome.";host=".$host, $usuario, $senha);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
//aqui use $this->
            $this->msgErro = $e->getMessage();
    }
    }
    public function logar($email, $senha)
    {
//aqui use $this->
        $sql = $this->pdo->prepare("SELECT id_usuario FROM usuarios WHERE email = :e AND senha = :s");
        $sql->bindValue(":e", $email);
        $sql->bindValue(":s", md5($senha));
        $sql->execute();

        if ($sql->rowCount() > 0)
        {
            $dado = $sql->fetch();
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['id_usuario'] = $dado['id_usuario'];
             return true;

        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
?>
```

Com essas modificações agora vai ser exibida a mensagem de erro caso ocorra algum problema para conectar ao BD. :)